# Replace special characters in a list python

Tags: python, list, replace

I would like to replace `':'`,`' '`, `'-'`, `'('`, and `')'` with an underscore for the items in this list:

```
columns = ['Region', 'Cat', 'Bld', 'Fbld', 'Ht(m)', 'H:W', 'Fperv', 'Froof', 'wall type', 'roof type', 'road-type', 'Tmn', 'Tmx', 'Notes']
```

So that:

```
columns = ['Region', 'Cat', 'Bld', 'Fbld', 'Ht_m', 'H_W', 'Fperv', 'Froof', 'wall_type', 'roof_type', 'road_type', 'Tmn', 'Tmx', 'Notes']
```

The goal is to replace all special characters and space so that it can be read into an sql table. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you provided a list of the special characters, you could:

- create a translation table using dict comprehension
- apply the translation to the elements of your list

code:

```
orig_list = ['Region', 'Cat', 'Bld', 'Fbld', 'Ht(m)', 'H:W', 'Fperv', 'Froof', 'wall type', 'roof type', 'road-type', 'Tmn', 'Tmx', 'Notes']

d = {ord(x):"_" for x in ":-() "}
new_list = [x.translate(d) for x in orig_list]

print(new_list)
```

result:

```
['Region', 'Cat', 'Bld', 'Fbld', 'Ht_m_', 'H_W', 'Fperv', 'Froof', 'wall type', 'roof type', 'road_type', 'Tmn', 'Tmx', 'Notes']
```

The classic regex solution as an alternative:

```
import re
new_list = [re.sub("[:\-() ]","_",x) for x in orig_list]
```